# Where to ask about checkout implementation

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about a checkout implementation using PHP, Zend, MVC, and MySQL.  Although the technologies used are web-development technologies, the question itself is about any design patterns I can use to help with the implementation in any RESTful environment.

I originally thought that https://stackoverflow.com/ was the place to ask this, but in the FAQ I was was presented with https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ as alternatives.

Where would be the best place to ask this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd ask it on Stack Overflow which I think is the best match. If it is more programmers.SE material, the community will vote to migrate it there.